How can i embed who commited/updated a page on github
Hi im currently writting some docs for my Discord bot Dev0, im using retype which is a static website generator that utalises json. howver it has an author function but i would like to know instead of me manually typing the author can i get which github user commited last too that specific page.
relevant links:

Docs: https://dev0.devvyy.xyz
Source: https://github.com/Dev0-bot/dev0-docs
Retype: https://retype.com/components/alert/

so far havent tried anything, i cannot find any projects that may help currently
